# stripe express connected accounts agreement type error

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

just wondering if you have ever had problems with express accounts and the agreement type in order to transfer to cross borders individuals. when I create an account for a user through my stripe dashboard, it creates the right agreement type which is "Recipient" but when a user creates the account by himself through the mobile app of the platform, the account will be created with the wrong agreement type which is the "full".
this is the error shown: Funds can't be sent to accounts located in CA when the account is under the `full` service agreement. To learn more, see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/service-agreement-types.

so, I tried by updating the code adding:

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.update(
  '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
  {
    tos_acceptance: {
      service_agreement: 'recipient',
    },
  }
);
```

but I would not work and when the user does the onboarding process from the mobile app, still appears with the wrong agreement type which is "full"

Comment: How is your mobile app creating the Accounts?

Comment: My platform is onboarding express connected accounts through the OAuth link. I already contacted the stripe support team and they told me to change the user’s capability to “transfer” like it is explained on this link : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts#specify-capabilities-for-an-account.     But it still doesn’t work.   Basically, what I need is that when an express account sings up through the OAuth link, they would appear on my dashboard with only the “transfers” capability and the “receipt ” agreement type.

Comment: Are you completing this step? https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts#token-request  If not they won't show up, as the process isn't complete until then.